# How to dynamically load a script tag that embeds flash video contents into div

Tags: flash, dynamic, append

The platform I am working on needs to dynamically load Javascript files that embed a flash video into a specified div. We shall call the div id "target". The Javascript file is appended into the div properly. However the flash video contents do not load.  How can I ensure that the embed scripts execute after the document has been loaded?

```
var div = document.getElementById("target");
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
newScript.setAttribute("src","http://www.go.url");
div.appendChild(newScript);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the load event from the document then load your script:

```
function loadJS() {
    var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true;
    s.src = '//www.goraceday.com/embed/14/1651/';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
}
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadJS, false);
else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', loadJS);
```